# How to update child elements when changing data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I build these elements ...

```
<svg>
  <g class="group">
    <text class="label">Hello</text>
  </g>
  <g class="group">
    <text class="label">World</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

... from following data:

```
[
  { id: 'a', label: 'Hello' },
  { id: 'b', label: 'World' },
]
```

Once create them, I change the data and run `.data()` again. However texts are not updated.

Codes https://jsfiddle.net/ginpei/r7b65fzt/ :

```
function render (data, container) {
  const group = container.selectAll('.group')
    .data(data, d => d.id)

  const entered = group.enter().append('g')
    .attr({
      class: 'group'
    })

  entered.append('text')
    .attr({
      class: 'label'
    })
    .attr({ y: (d, i) => 20 + i * 20})

  const label = group.selectAll('.label')
    .text(d => d.label)
}
```

At the second time, it looks data bound to `.group` is updated but data bound to `.label` is not. I expected that data would be set as well as the first time.

How to update them?

Actually I found it works if I add `.data()` for child elements.

```
  const label = container.selectAll('.label')
    .data(data, d => d.id)  // <--- added
    .text(d => d.label)
```

Is this the correct way to update them?

It would be great to update them by easier way because my actual codes have a lot of descendant elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is quite simple: just change `selectAll` to `select`.

```
const label = group.select('.label')
    .text(d => d.label);
```

To understand why, here is a table I've made with the differences between `select` and `selectAll`:

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

Pay attention to the *propagates data* versus *doesn't propagate data*.

And here is your code with that change and a `setTimeout` to change the data:

```js
// d3.js 3.x

const container = d3.select('body').append('svg')

function render(data, container) {
  const group = container.selectAll('.group')
    .data(data, d => d.id)

  const entered = group.enter().append('g')
    .attr({
      class: 'group'
    })
  entered.append('text')
    .attr({
      class: 'label'
    })
    .attr({
      y: (d, i) => 20 + i * 20
    })
  const label = group.select('.label')
    .text(d => d.label);

}

// first try
const data1 = [{
  id: 'a',
  label: 'Hello'
}, {
  id: 'b',
  label: 'World'
}, ]
render(data1, container)

// update
const data2 = [{
  id: 'a',
  label: 'Goodbye'
}, {
  id: 'b',
  label: 'Universe'
}, ]
setTimeout(function() {
  render(data2, container)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Your code won't work with v4 (or v5).